# Why SynchronousQueue allows other threads to take in random order?

Tags: java, multithreading, sorting

I am trying to implement a small program that will sort out an array/vector of integers in ascending order using SynchronousQueue.

The approach I took over this was to create a pool of threads, where each thread would sort the elements only *once* in ascending order by iterating through them and comparing elements on positions *i* and *i+1* and swapping them.

So I have created a class that does this swap and takes as arguments the *iteration* number, two SynchronousQueues and the array itself as follows:

```
class OrderAsc extends Thread {
int length;
int iteration;
SynchronousQueue<ArrayList> st, dr; 
ArrayList<Integer> vector;
boolean swapMade;

    OrderAsc( int iteration, SynchronousQueue<ArrayList> st, SynchronousQueue<ArrayList> dr, ArrayList<Integer> vector) throws InterruptedException{

        this.length = vector.size();
        this.st = st;
        this.dr = dr;
        this.vector = vector;
        this.iteration = iteration;
        this.swapMade = false;
    }

    // Rularea thread-ului
    @Override
    public void run(){

        if(iteration > 0){

            try {
                vector = st.take();
                System.out.println(iteration + " get " + vector);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }

        // System.out.println(iteration + " >>> " + vector);


        for(int i = 0; i < length-1; i++){
            if(vector.get(i) > vector.get(i+1)){

                int tmp = vector.get(i);
                vector.set(i, vector.get(i+1));
                vector.set(i+1, tmp);

                swapMade = true;
            }
        }

        if(swapMade){
            try {

                dr.put(vector);
                System.out.println(iteration + " put " + vector);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        } else { 
            // Display result
            System.out.println(vector);
        }
        System.exit(0);

    }

}
```

In the main class, I am creating an ArrayList of objects of this class as follows:

```
ArrayList<OrderAsc> orderFilter = new ArrayList<OrderAsc>(n+2);
            for(int i = 0; i < n + 2; i++){
                orderFilter.add(i, new OrderAsc(i, st, dr, vector));
                st = dr;
                dr = new SynchronousQueue<ArrayList>();                    

            }

            for(int i=0; i < n + 2; i++){
                orderFilter.get(i).setDaemon(true);
                orderFilter.get(i).start();
            }
```

Having in consideration the implementation of *OrderAsc* object, the first thread will do a sort iteration on the data, then it will PUT into the *dr* queue the result. Then, the next thread which is blocked will wait for the first one to *TAKE* this result, filter it again, and then send it to the next until the entire array is sorted.

Unexpectedly, it seems that the threads aren't waiting for those SynchronousQueues all the time, and for some reasons they sometimes take the data randomly like below:

```
1 get [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6]
0 put [4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6]
1 put [4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6]
2 get [4, 3, 2, 1, 5, 6]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 5 seconds)
```

Is there a different way that the SynchronousQueue works and I've implemented it wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  You appear to have a chain of threads where each one does a single swap of two element.  I assume you want something inefficient so you can see how threads work with queues?

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes, I want something inefficient to see how threads work. In each iteration, I am doing a swap of the elements which would be the next iteration of the ASC sort

Comment: Tricky program....i noticed that you are trying 'put' and 'take' on different Synque type objects....have you tried a single synque program..?

Comment: I have tried to use a single synchronousqueue but it seems that the threads are fired all at a time, and they don't wait to read/write from the queue as expected. They just do it randomly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried rewriting your program with one synchronous queue...
In short the thread 0 puts in the initial unsorted vector and
the remaining threads start sorting in an iteration wise manner.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue;


class OrderAsc extends Thread {
    int length;
    int iteration;
    SynchronousQueue<ArrayList> st, dr; 
    ArrayList<Integer> vector;
    boolean swapMade;

    OrderAsc( int iteration, SynchronousQueue<ArrayList> st, SynchronousQueue<ArrayList> dr, ArrayList<Integer> vector) throws InterruptedException{
        this.length = vector.size();
        this.st = st;
        this.dr = dr;
        this.vector = vector;
        this.iteration = iteration;
        this.swapMade = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){

        if ( iteration == 0 ){
            try {

                System.out.println("\n  " + iteration  + " put " + vector);

                st.put(vector);

                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                return;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{

            try {
                vector = st.take();
                // System.out.println("\n Take in Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                System.out.println(iteration + " take " + vector);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }

        } 


        for(int i = 0; i < vector.size() - 1; i++){

            if(vector.get(i) > vector.get(i+1)){
                int tmp = vector.get(i);
                vector.set(i, vector.get(i+1));
                vector.set(i+1, tmp);

                swapMade = true;
            }

        }


        if(swapMade){
                //System.out.println("\n Swap Done in  Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());

            try {
                st.put(vector);

                System.out.println(iteration + " sorted " + vector);

            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex);
            }
        }  

        //System.out.println("\n Exiting Thread : " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        // System.exit(0);

    }


    public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<OrderAsc> orderFilter = new ArrayList<OrderAsc>(5);

        ArrayList<Integer> vector = new ArrayList<Integer>(6);
        vector.add(4);
        vector.add(1);
        vector.add(3);
        vector.add(5);
        vector.add(6);
        vector.add(2);


        System.out.println("\n Unsorted Array " + vector + "\n\n");

        int n = vector.size();

        //vector.add(1);
        //vector.add(5);

        SynchronousQueue<ArrayList> st1 = new SynchronousQueue<ArrayList>();
        SynchronousQueue<ArrayList> dr1 = new SynchronousQueue<ArrayList>();

        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            try {

                orderFilter.add(i, new OrderAsc(i, st1, dr1, vector));

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //st1 = dr1;
            //dr1 = new SynchronousQueue<ArrayList>();                    
        }

        for(int i=0; i < n - 1; i++){
            //orderFilter.get(i).setDaemon(true);
             orderFilter.get(i).start();
        }


        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("\n Voila Thanks Threads and the  Sorted Array Is ");

        for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(" " + vector.get(i) +  " ");
        }   

    }

}
```

Comment: By the way ...to be honest ...there is not much rewriting....its virtually your code except the synchroqueue dr is now defunct.....and thread-0 ie first iteration only puts in the unsorted arraylist into the queue object and gets out of the way for the remaining threads to start sorting....

Comment: By the way...nice coding...nice problem ...helped me understand the concept of sync queue